# (SOAP-ENV:Server) Cannot use object of type stdClass as array - magento - ruby

Tags: ruby, magento, soap, savon

I'm trying to create a customer in magento using soap. I use Savon gem for ruby, make a call like:

```
@client.call(:customer_customer_create, message: {
                          session_id: "id",
                          customer_data: {
                            email: email,
                            firstname: firstname,
                            lastname: lastname,
                            password: SecureRandom.base64,
                            'store_id' => @store_id
                          }
                        })
```

Getting the error:

```
(SOAP-ENV:Server) Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

on this call. Can't really trace it or know of any other ways of debugging. This is run from a job and it started failing a while ago. Shop owner said that he added Magento patch SUPEE-8788.
Is there a setting in magento that we need to activate so that the calls work?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: we found out that it is happening because of a magento plugin, something called  Clang extension. i think in the end the client turned that off and it was fine, but i would really like to know if there is a solution for this issue.